# Show that the derivative of this function is positive

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, binomial-distribution

> Suppose that $n>1$, $g\in(0,1)$ and $f(g)\in(0,1)$. Suppose that 
>   $\frac{df(g)}{dg}\geq0$.
>
> Define $B(g,n)$ as:
>
> $B(g,n)=\sum _{k=1}^n \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}g^{n-k}(1-g)^{k-1}(1-(1-f(g))^k)$
>
> Show that:
>
> $\frac{dB(g,n)}{dg}>0$.

Some of these assumptions can be relaxed (for example the $\frac{df(g)}{dg}\geq0$ I suspect), but I am not especially interested in that.

What I have done:

1. I have shown that this is the case for $n=2$, $n=3$ and $n=4$, but did not find any pattern that helped me generalize to $n$.
2. I took the derivative with Mathematica and obtained that little monster:
   $
   \frac{dB(g,n)}{dg}=-\frac{g^n \left(-n \left(\frac{(g-1) f(g)+1}{g}\right)^{n-1} \left(\frac{(g-1) f'(g)+f(g)}{g}-\frac{(g-1) f(g)+1}{g^2}\right)-n \left(\frac{1}{g}\right)^{n+1}\right)}{g-1}-\frac{n g^{n-1} \left(\left(\frac{1}{g}\right)^n-\left(\frac{(g-1) f(g)+1}{g}\right)^n\right)}{g-1}+\frac{g^n \left(\left(\frac{1}{g}\right)^n-\left(\frac{(g-1) f(g)+1}{g}\right)^n\right)}{(g-1)^2}$.
3. (Here I might be wrong) I think that the problem can be slightly simplified by assuming that $\frac{df(g)}{dg}=0$. Because assuming $\frac{df(g)}{dg}>0$ only "helps us" in proving the that the derivative is positive, then it suffices to show that our desired result holds when $\frac{df(g)}{dg}=0$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looking at your tags, it seems this problem occurs in a probabilistic context. Have you tried to show that this function is the cdf (cumulative distribution function) of a certain random variable, which has the property to have a $\geq 0$ derivative ?

Comment: You need not calculate the derivative to show it's positive

Comment: Thank you @JeanMarie. You are right, this occurs in a probabilistic context. I have not tried what you propose, but I think that there can be something in it. However, I am unsure on how to do it. Do you have any hint on how I can start?

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Mark, how would you show it without calculating the derivative? With Jean Marie's strategy?

Comment: Have you tried what happens for low values if $n$, like $n=2$ for example ?

Comment: Yes, the derivative is positive then. I have tried with $n=2$, $n=3$ and $n=4$ trying to find any pattern, but I have miserably failed on that.

Comment: You just argue that adding small enough value to g makes the expression larger. But in fact if it's true that the derivative is positive, regardless of g, it must be the case that any increment (large or small) must make the expression larger (assuming that g remains inside [0,1])

Comment: It looks connected to a mixture (in the probabilistic meaning) of cdf of what is called **order statistics**

Comment: Thank you @JeanMarie, now I understand the reason why this can be proven conceptually. I hope that tomorrow I will manage to prove it with the new tool you gave me (going to bed now) :)

Comment: @Lorena_dok: A minor side note: expressions (especially algebraic ones) can be simplified by Mathematica with the commands `Simplify[]` and, if you are willing to wait a bit longer for the result, `FullSimplify[]` (which will try a larger palette of techniques).

Comment: @Lorena_dok: According to Mathematica, $B(g,n) = \frac 1 {g-1} \big([1-(g-1)f(g) ]^n - 1 \big)$, which could be proved by induction with a bit of patience. The closed form obtained by Mathematica for the derivative now follows easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all (including those who helped in [Pure algebra: Show that this expression is positive](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2310460/pure-algebra-show-that-this-expression-is-positive)) we have shown the result. I will summarize it for those who can be interested.

Note that $B(g,n)$ simplifies to

$B(g,n)=\sum _{k=1}^n \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}g^{n-k}(1-g)^{k-1}(1-(1-f(g))^k)=\frac{-1+(1-f(g)+gf(g))^n}{-1+g}$.

Hence

$\frac{dB(g,n)}{dg}=\frac{(g-1)n(g-(g-1)(1-f(g)))^{n-1}(f(g)+(g-1)f'(g))-((g-(g-1)(1-f(g)))^n-1)}{(g-1)^2}$.

Because $\frac{dB(g,n)}{dg}$ is increasing in $f'(g)$, and we have assumed that $f'(g)\geq0$, we can can now set $f'(g)=0$. This simplifies the previous derivative to

$\frac{dB(g,n)}{dg}=\frac{1-(1-g)nf(g)(1-(1-g)f(g))^{n-1}-(1-(1-g)f(g))^n}{(g-1)^2}.$

We want to show that this derivative is positive. To do so, set $t=1-(1-g)f(g)$ in the previous expression and eliminate the (positive) denominator. Now we need to show that

$f_n(t):= 1-n(1-t)t^{n-1}+t^n=1-nt^{n-1}+(n+1)t^n>0$.

Note that

$f'_n(t)=-n(n-1)t^{n-2}+n(n+1)t^{n-1}$,

where $t_0=0$ and $t_n=\frac{n-1}{n+1}$ make $f'_n(t)=0$. Since $f''_n(t_n)>0$, we conclude that $t_n$ is a minimum.

Now remains to show that $f_t(t_n)>0$.

$f_t(t_n)=1-n(\frac{n-1}{n+1})^{n-1}+(n+1)(\frac{n-1}{n+1})^{n}=1-(\frac{n-1}{n+1})^{n-1}>0$.

Thanks to everyone who contributed!

Answer (score 1):

Note: I am in the process of simplifying and correcting this answer. I realized some more stuff was wrong.

$B(g,n)=\sum _{k=1}^n \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}g^{n-k}(1-g)^{k-1}(1-(1-f(g))^k)  $

Now let $X_g(k) = 1 - (1 - f(g))^k$
$B(g,n)=    (1-g)^{-1}\sum _{k=1}^n \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}g^{n}(1-g)^{k-1}X_g(k)$

$X_g(0) = 0$ so we can expand the summation limit to include $i=0$
$B(g,n) = (1-g)^{-1}\sum _{k=0}^n \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}g^{n}(1-g)^{k-1}X_g(k)$

Using $X_g(0) = 0$ we can include $0$ in the summation indices
$B(g,n) =(1-g)^{-1}\sum _{k=0}^n \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}g^{n-k}(1-g)^{k}X_g(k) $

Notation: Let the random variable $K_{a,b}$ be the result of tossing $b$ independent coins with $P(\text{heads}) = a$ and counting the number of heads. (This is called a binomial random variable with parameters $(a, b)$).
Reinterpret $B(g,n)$ as an expression about expected value involving the binomial random variable $K_{1-g,n}$.

$B(g,n) =(1-g)^{-1}\mathbb{E}[X_g(K_{1-g,n})]$
$ =(1-g)^{-1}\mathbb{E}[1 - (1 - f(g))^{K_{1-g,n}}]$
$ =(1-g)^{-1}(\mathbb{E}[1] - \mathbb{E}[(1 - f(g))^{K_{1-g,n}}])$
$ =(1-g)^{-1}(1 - \mathbb{E}[(1 - f(g))^{K_{1-g,n}}])$

Now decompose $K_{1-g,n}$ as the sum of $n$ independent coin tosses $K_{1-g,n} = Y_{1-g}^{(1)} + Y_{1-g}^{(2)} + ... Y_{1-g}^{(n)}$ where $Y_{1-g}^{(i)}$ is the $i$th independent coin which takes $1$ with probability $1-g$ and $0$ with probability $g$.

$B(g,n) =(1-g)^{-1}(1 - \mathbb{E}[(1 - f(g))^{\sum_{i=1}^nY_{1-g}^{(i)}}])$
$ =(1-g)^{-1}(1 - \mathbb{E}[\prod_{i=1}^n(1 - f(g))^{Y_{1-g}^{(i)}}])$

Expectation distributes over products when random variables are independent.
$B(g,n) =(1-g)^{-1}(1 - \prod_{i=1}^n\mathbb{E}[(1 - f(g))^{Y_{1-g}^{(i)}}])$
$ =(1-g)^{-1}(1 - \prod_{i=1}^n\mathbb{E}[(1 - f(g))^{Y_{1-g}^{(1)}}])$
$ =(1-g)^{-1}(1 - \mathbb{E}[(1 - f(g))^{Y_{1-g}^{(1)}}]^n)$

It is easy to calculate $\mathbb{E}[(1 - f(g))^{Y_{1-g}^{(1)}}]$ since the two cases are $Y_{1-g}^{(1)} = 0$ and $Y_{1-g}^{(1)} = 0$.
$\mathbb{E}[(1 - f(g))^{Y_{1-g}^{(1)}}] $
$= P(Y_{1-g}^{(1)} = 0)(1 - f(g))^0 + P(Y_{1-g}^{(1)} = 1)(1 - f(g))^1$
$ = g + (1-g)(1-f(g))$
$ = g + 1 - f(g) - g + gf(g)$
$ = 1 - f(g) + gf(g)$

Then substituting we have
$B(g,n) =(1-g)^{-1}(1 - (1 - f(g) + gf(g))^n)$

Remember that to prove $\frac{dB}{dg}(g,n) \ge 0$, we only need to show $B(g,n)$ is nondecreasing in $g$. Equivalently, we can show $\log B(g,n)$ is nondecreasing in $g$.

$\log B(g,n) = -\log(1-g) + \log(1 - (1-f(g) + gf(g))^n)$

We can use the power series expansion $-\log(1-x) = \sum_{j=1}^\infty x^j/j$ on both $\log$ terms. You can see there are no issues of divergence by verifying $g \in (0,1)$ and $(1-f(g) + gf(g))^n \in (0,1)$

$\log B(g,n) = \sum_{j=1}^\infty g^j/j - \sum_{j=1}^\infty(1-f(g) + gf(g))^{nj}/j$
$= \sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{[ g^j  - (1-f(g) + gf(g))^{nj}]}{j}$

Comment: This is really helpful Mark! Isn't there a small typo when you assume that $X^k=(1-(1-f(g+\epsilon))^k)$? (mind that only the second part of $X$ is raised to $k$, not the entire $X$)
Also, I did not know about the simplification where one can get rid of the factorials, I am trying to understand the equivalence...

Comment: Yes! I noticed that mistake I'm still thinking if it can be fixed... The equivalence is called the binomial theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem

Comment: Alright I think this is correct now...

Comment: @Mark: Nice try but... if $f=\frac 1 2$ then $B(g,n)= \dfrac { \left( \frac {g+1} 2 \right)^n  - 1} {g-1}$ - clearly not locally constant with respect to $g$. Do never trust long chains of reasoning!

Comment: @AlexM. Agreed, unless I saw that every link in the chain is correct. Then I have no other choice :)

In any case, which part are you saying is wrong? I'm showing B(g,n) is monotonic in g, not locally constant

Comment: @AlexM. I think we have computed the same expression for B(g,n) haven't we? (Set $\epsilon=0$ and substitute the last line) It's just that I avoid the final computation of derivative

Comment: Thanks for all the help Mark! There are a couple of steps that I am not able to follow (not your fault, just my ignorance in this field). Now I am trying to prove it in a more straightforward way. If I don't succeed, I'll come back to your solution and learn everything I have to learn to follow it :)

Answer (score 1):

This is not a full solution, but some possibly helpful thoughts too long to fit a comment.

Notice that

$$B(g,n) = \sum _{k=1} ^n \frac {n!} {k!(n-k)!} g^{n-k} (1-g)^{k-1} - \sum _{k=1} ^n \frac {n!} {k!(n-k)!} g^{n-k} (1-g)^{k-1} (1-f(g))^k = \\
\frac 1 {1-g} \sum _{k=1} ^n \frac {n!} {k!(n-k)!} g^{n-k} (1-g)^k - \frac 1 {1-g} \sum _{k=1} ^n \frac {n!} {k!(n-k)!} g^{n-k} (1-g)^k (1-f(g))^k = \\
\frac 1 {1-g} \{ [g + (1-g)]^n - 1 \} - \frac 1 {1-g} \{ [g + (1-g)(1-f(g))]^n - 1 \} = \\
\frac 1 {g-1} \{ [g - (g-1)(1-f(g))]^n - 1 \} \ ,$$

whence

$$\frac {\Bbb d B(g,n)} {\Bbb d g} = \frac { \{n [g - (g-1)(1-f(g))]^{n-1} [1 - (1-f(g)) + (g-1) f'(g)] \} (g-1)} {(g-1)^2} - \frac {\{ [g - (g-1)(1-f(g))]^n - 1 \}} {(g-1)^2} = \\
\frac {\Bbb d B(g,n)} {\Bbb d g} = \frac { \{n [g - (g-1)(1-f(g))]^{n-1} [f(g) + (g-1) f'(g)] \} (g-1)} {(g-1)^2} - \frac {\{ [g - (g-1)(1-f(g))]^n - 1 \}} {(g-1)^2} \ .$$

Since the denominator is positive, you have then to show that

$$\{n [g - (g-1)(1-f(g))]^{n-1} [f(g) + (g-1) f'(g)] \} (g-1) - \{ [g - (g-1)(1-f(g))]^n - 1 \} \ge 0 \ .$$

Notice that

$$g - (g-1)(1-f(g)) = 1 + (g-1)f(g) < 1 \ ,$$

whence it follows that

$$- \{ [g - (g-1)(1-f(g))]^n - 1 \} \ge 0 \ .$$

and that

$$n [g - (g-1)(1-f(g))]^{n-1} \to 0 \ ,$$

so that $\lim \limits _{n \to \infty} \dfrac {\Bbb d B} {\Bbb d g} \ge 0$. Unfortunately, it is not clear whether this limit is uniform.

It also follows that a sufficient (but not necessary) condition to get the desired conclusion is $f + (g-1)f' \le 0$.

Comment: Thanks for this very useful answer! Do you buy my argument that if we show the result for $\frac{df(g)}{dg}=0$ it would be sufficient, since the case when $\frac{df(g)}{dg}>0$ only "helps us"? If you do, now the problem boils down to proving that
$1-(1-g)ns(1-(1-g)s)^{n-1}-(1-(1-g)s)^n>0$,
where $s\in(0,1)$ and represents our previous function $f(g)$. Do you think that this argument is valid?