# Pure algebra: Show that this expression is positive

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> Suppose that $n\geq2$, $g\in(0,1)$ and $s\in(0,1)$. Show that:
>
> $1-(1-g)ns(1-(1-g)s)^{n-1}-(1-(1-g)s)^n > 0 $

What I have done:

1. I have confirmed that given my assumptions this inequality holds with the help of Mathematica. Here a picture of how the function looks like. In the y-axis the value of the function and in the x-axis the value of $s$.

[image]

2. I have done my best with basic algebra (multiplications, divisions, sums...), but have not managed to get anything out of it. I guess that I need some extra trick that I am unaware of.

Any solution/idea on how this can be solved will be highly appreciated!

Thank you in advance.

PS. This problem emerged from trying to solve [Show that the derivative of this function is positive](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2308709/show-that-the-derivative-of-this-function-is-positive). Thanks to the contribution of many, we arrived to this "simple" inequality. Because this new problem is conceptually miles a part from the old one, I created this new post. If we manage to solve it, I will go back to the other one to complete the final answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $h=1-(1-g)s$, so that $(1-g)s=1-h$, which means the inequality can be rewritten as $1-(1-h)nh^{n-1}-h^n\gt0$, or

$$1\gt h^n+nh^{n-1}(1-h)$$

Now $g\in(0,1)$ implies $1-g\in(0,1)$, so that $s\in(0,1)$ implies $1-h=(1-g)s\in(0,1)$, which in turn implies $h\in(0,1)$.  If we now use the binomial expansion

$$(a+b)^n=a^n+na^{n-1}b+\cdots+b^n\gt a^n+na^{n-1}b\qquad\text{if }a,b\gt0\text{ and }n\ge2$$

with $a=h$ and $b=1-h$, we have

$$1=(h+1-h)^n\gt h^n+nh^{n-1}(1-h)$$

as desired.

Answer (score 1):

The expression is indeed simple if you set $t=1-(1-g)s$:

$$f_n(t):=1-n(1-t)t^{n-1}+t^n=1-nt^{n-1}+(n+1)t^n,$$ where is $t$ in $(0,1)$.

The derivative is

$$f'_n(t)=-n(n-1)t^{n-2}+n(n+1)t^{n-1},$$ which cancels at $t_0=0$ (a maximum) and $t_n=\dfrac{n-1}{n+1}$ (a minimum, which is in $(0,1)$).

Remains to show that $f_n(t_n)>0$:

$$1-n\left(\frac{n-1}{n+1}\right)^{n-1}+(n+1)\left(\frac{n-1}{n+1}\right)^n=1-\left(\frac{n-1}{n+1}\right)^{n-1}>0.$$

---

The plot for $n=2,3,4,5$:

[image]